# How do you disable Microsoft Code's console debugging messages?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you disable Microsoft Code's console debugging messages?

I would like to do this in order to launch Microsoft Code from the console and not have the debugging messages interfere with the console.

Comment: I would like to tag this microsoft-code but I lack the reputation required to do so. :/

Answer (score 0):

`code --v=-1`

The Electron framework allows certain Chrome commandline arguments. The `--v` argument allows you to set the debug verbosity. The value `-1` disables all messages.